# how to set custom font for entire application in lollipop

Tags: android, overriding, typeface, custom-font

I want to set a custom font to all of textviews in My app.I used below code

```
public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets)
    {
        try
        {
            final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),customFontFileNameInAssets);
            Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible (true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null,customFontTypeface);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("getMessage",e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Log.e("Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
        }

    }
```

and call method as below

```
TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(this, "DEFAULT", getTypeFace());
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(this, "MONOSPACE", getTypeFace());
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(this, "SERIF", getTypeFace());
        TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", getTypeFace());
```

this code work in android before android 5 good but it dont work in lollipop.
I search alot but I dont find any things.

Comment: You should also implement like '<style name="TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">serif-monospace</item>
    </style>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have did this using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

**in your Application class in the #onCreate() method.**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Roboto-RobotoRegular.ttf")
                            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                            .build()
            );
    //....
}
```

**Wrap the Activity Context:**

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}
```

Comment: thanks your code in activities very good but in dialogs  it dont work.any idea?

Comment: @zohrehkh if you have a base activity and you have implemented attachTheBaseContext method. It should work for every Activity which inherits BaseActivity

Comment: It doesn't work for views created in code, only via XML.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it by overriding application default fonts:

Create a class **FontsOverride**:

```
public final class FontsOverride {

public static void setDefaultFont(Context context,
                                  String staticTypefaceFieldName, String fontAssetName) {
    final Typeface regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            fontAssetName);
    replaceFont(staticTypefaceFieldName, regular);
}

private static void replaceFont(String staticTypefaceFieldName,
                                final Typeface newTypeface) {
    try {
        final Field staticField = Typeface.class
                .getDeclaredField(staticTypefaceFieldName);
        staticField.setAccessible(true);
        staticField.set(null, newTypeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Create an `Application` Class or add it to your current one if you already have:

```
public class AppController extends Application {

// add a folder named `fonts` under `assets` folder
// add theme here
String customFont1 = "fonts/IRANSans-Light-web.ttf";
String customFont2 = "fonts/font2.ttf";
String customFont3 = "fonts/font3.ttf";
String customFont4 = "fonts/font4.ttf";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // override default fonts
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "DEFAULT", customFont1);
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "MONOSPACE", customFont2);
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SERIF", customFont3);
    FontsOverride.setDefaultFont(this, "SANS_SERIF", customFont4);

}
```

}

Add typeface on your theme in `style`

```
<!-- Application theme -->
<style name="myTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
```

And finally, add it to your `manifest` in `Application` tag:

```
    <application
    android:name="path.AppController"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/myTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

(I've tested it and it works on `Lolipop too)

Answer (score 0):

Assume your selected font is `serif-monospace`, then you should also implement like

```
<style name="TextView" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">serif-monospace</item>
    </style>
```

and use like this

```
 <TextView
   style="@style/TextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a recursive function and kept this in my BaseActivity:

```
 public static void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {
    try {
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
            for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View child = vg.getChildAt(i);
                overrideFonts(context, child);
            }
        }
        if (v.getClass() == TextView.class) {
            if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("bold")) {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
            } else {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFont(context));
            }
        }

        if (v.getClass() == AppCompatTextView.class) {
            if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("bold")) {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
            } else {
                ((TextView) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFont(context));
            }
        }

        if (v.getClass() == Button.class) {
            ((Button) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
        }
        if (v.getClass() == AppCompatButton.class) {
            ((Button) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
        }

        if (v.getClass() == TextInputLayout.class) {
            ((TextInputLayout) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
        }
        if (v.getClass() == TextInputEditText.class) {
            ((TextInputEditText) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFont(context));
        }
        if (v.getClass() == AppCompatEditText.class) {
            ((AppCompatEditText) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFont(context));
        }
        if (v.getClass() == EditText.class) {
            if (v.getTag() != null && v.getTag().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("bold")) {
                ((EditText) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFontBold(context));
            } else {
                ((EditText) v).setTypeface(FontUtils.getFont(context));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Font Exception", e.toString());
    }
}
```

FontUtils :

```
public abstract class FontUtils {

    public static Typeface regular, bold;

    public static Typeface getFont(Context appContext) {
    if (regular == null) {
        regular = Typeface.createFromAsset(appContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf");
    }
    return regular;
    }


    public static Typeface getFontBold(Context appContext) {
    if (bold == null) {
        bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(appContext.getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf");
    }
    return bold;
    }
}
```

You can add your own cases plus i use the tag in the xml for bold and regular fonts

```
android:tag="bold"
```

Call the method in onCreate of the BaseActivity like this :

```
View contentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
overrideFonts(this, contentView);
```

Make sure you call the super.OnCreate after setContentView in your activity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Working with fonts](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html).

From I/O 2017 you can now use the following in xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lobster"/>
```

Google added this support for O devices, but also , I quote:

> The Support Library 26.0 Beta provides support to the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android API version 14 and higher.